# Why does gcc -O3 produce wildly different assembly for the same function?

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

I have a loop in a physics engine which detects collisions like this:

```
  // now check for collisions
  // we only allow 1 collision per 2 partcles per frame so the
  // one with the lower index will always "collide" first
  for (size_t j = 0; j < m_particles.size(); j++) {
    for (size_t k = j + 1; k < m_particles.size(); k++) {
      m_particles[j].collide(m_particles[k]);
    }
  }
```

I made a change to use a double buffer for the particles internally. (As an aside; this was done so that I can detect errors and go back 1 time step to correct). The double buffers were implemented with 2 pointers which I swap after this loop. So now we have:

```
  // now check for collisions
  // we only allow 1 collision per 2 partcles per frame so the
  // one with the lower index will always "collide" first
  for (size_t j = 0; j < m_current_particles->size(); j++) {
    for (size_t k = j + 1; k < m_current_particles->size(); k++) {
      (*m_current_particles)[j].collide((*m_current_particles)[k]);
    }
  }

std::swap(m_current_particles, m_previous_particles);
```

In both cases, the containers are `std::vector`.

With the same driver program, the second is over 10x slower. Nothing inside the `collide()` function has changed, and I can reproduce by creating a build with only the switch to the double buffer and no other changes at all.

Eventually I broke out the profiling tools and sure enough... the assembly for the `collide()` function is completely different, despite identical source. In either case it there is an explicit `callq` to a `collide` subroutine, so it's not inlining the collision function into the loop in the former case.

In the former case:

- All Vector `operator` overloads on the particles' Vector (my own vector implementation, not a `std::vector`) members have been translated to inline assembly.
- Makes heavy use of the `%xmm` registers
- Composed of a bunch of dedicated floating point multiply, add, sqrt, instructions.
- Self contained subroutine, only has conditional jumps back to be beginning as you'd expect for something like this.

In the performance regression case:

- Minimal inlining, context switches to call subroutines for all Vector operations.
- Almost no use of `%xmm` registers, everything is `%rax`, `%rbx`, etc.
- Even inspecting the subroutines, they seem to be not as well optimized (a lot more assembly, not a lot of usage of dedicated mul/sqrt instructions).
- Context switches many times which incurs a huge performance overhead.

Try as I might I cannot convince the compiler to produce something like the original assembly with the new code.

- Tried marking everything `inline` which is called in `collide()` (although I hear these days the compiler largely ignores you if you do that).
- For fun, tried manually writing all the math by just accessing members and doing it in the function instead of calling their functions / operators. No dice. Did kick me down to about a 7x performance hit instead of 10x, though.
- Messing about with calling the function in varying ways inside the loop.
- Making an `auto& local_particles = m_current_particles` local in case the compiler was upset about the scope of the pointer.
- Making a copy of the array locally and calling with that, making it look the exact same as the original loop, then copying the array back. No luck, and this wouldn't scale even it it resolved.
- Pleading with God.

Is this just a case of the compiler's insane brain lining up in just the right way in the former case, or has my calling convention somehow broken an invariant I've held to be true between these two sources?

Here's the relevant parts of the call graph:

Former case (everything's been inlined):

[image]

Regression (explicit calls are obvious):

[image]

Needed to be collapsed to fit reasonably, the calls below `collide()` are the `operator-` overload for Vector and the Vector constructor itself to create the temporary object.

Edit: With -O2 on the former case, it inlines the the expensive vector subtraction operator but not the ctor call for the temporary. Runs in about 1.3x vs -O3. -O2 and -O3 in the regression case seem essentially the same.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you add a local container, like `local_container = *m_current_particles;` and then use that in place of all your uses of the `m_current_particles` pointer? Maybe the optimizer is 'worried' about that pointer?? (Just guessing, really - but that would seem to set it back to closer to your original.)

Comment: ... but I guess you'd then have to have `*m_current_particles = local_particles;` after the loops - do those copies add a lot of work? Maybe make the local a reference object?

Comment: I'll add the reference trick into my "tried" list, forgot about one. No dice. Just tried the copy as well. Same thing. With the test driver the copy doesn't seem to matter too much but making a copy of all particles in the system during every main loop probably wont' scale anyway.

Comment: -O3 may or may not be better than -O2.

Comment: What happens if you put the collide function in its own source file?

Comment: OK - Another stab: If you're passing the `m_current_particles` pointer as an argument used by the code you've shown, have you tried adding the [`restrict` qualifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict)? From the linked page: *The intended use of the restrict qualifier (like the register storage class) is to promote optimization...*

Comment: Can you boil this down to a [mcve] with the slow and/or fast asm?  That might show you whether it's a potential aliasing / escape-analysis problem or not, although like Adrian that would be my first guess for surrounding context impacting how something is optimized.  A factor of 10x is probably more than can be explained by microarchitectural potholes like the JCC erratum on Skylake-family (if a branch instruction ends up touching a 32-byte boundary.)

Comment: Have you tried `auto& local_particles = *m_current_particles`?

Comment: BTW, C `restrict` is available as `__restrict`, as an extension in most C++ compilers (including all the mainstream x86 ones), @AdrianMole

Comment: @Peter Indeed - And, IIRC, GCC makes quite 'aggressive' use of `__restrict`.

Comment: @AdrianMole: Right, yes, if possible aliasing was the problem causing spill/reload or blocking vectorization, `__restrict` typically *will* fix it in GCC, if you apply it to all relevant pointers.  (Sometimes even ones you only read through, especially if any locals have their address escape the function, or you update non-local vars in the loop, e.g. member vars)

Comment: @brenzo: Since you're seeing different asm for the `collide` function, is the version that gets called a `.clone.constprop...` version of `collide` in the fast case, or is it the full version?  If the latter, probably some IPA optimization went differently.  (Inter Procedural Analysis).  Or else it depends on some `static` var, and GCC can no longer prove that it's a constant or something?  Also, why isn't it inlining?  Small to medium functions can be worth inlining into hot loops.  Maybe try `__attribute__((always_inline))` on collide just to see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried clang to see if it's fast for both?  And/or different arch/tuning options like `-O3 -march=native`, `-ffast-math`, `-mtune=znver1` etc. to see if anything makes GCC dramatically different, in a good or bad way?  Different tuning options will have different inline / unroll heuristic thresholds which might make a difference to GCC or clang's choice of strategy.

Comment: What do you mean "context switch"?  Pretty sure you don't mean the OS scheduling a different thread because this one did `yield()` or blocked...  Are you misusing that to describe a `call`?  Also, if this is still FP math, how is the compiler using mostly integer regs?  When you say "inline assembly", I think you mean that functions were inlined, not that you used some wrapper function with an `asm("" : "=r"(out) : "r" (in));` implementation...  Also, what types are involved here?  `m_particles` is what, a `std::vector` of some custom 3D or 2D geometry `Vector` class?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. -O2 and -O3 are similar in this case, and neither help with the regression. Updated post. What's the logic on moving it to its own source file?

Comment: @AdrianMole I'll try __restrict thanks

Comment: @PeterCordes yes you're correct, I wasn't being precise with that terminology. I'll try your suggestions, thank you. As for the types, `m_particles` is a `std::vector<Particle<float>>`  which contains `Vector<float>`s for velocity and position. In the latter case, we're just dealing with a pointer to the same `std::vector` type

Comment: If you're not going to show any source or asm for the function that optimized differently, you definitely need to be precise with your terminology!  A link on https://godbolt.org/ (or at least github or something) with the full code would be much better for anyone who wanted to check this out, instead of just making random guesses.  An [mcve] that fits in an SO question would be even better.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm happy to provide source and asm if you'd like, I didn't want to bloat the post too much. The project is on github https://github.com/satisfiedghost/simulator but does not contain the problems in question, those are local to my laptop at the moment.

Comment: @PeterCordes I can attempt a minimal reproduceable example but it's unlikely I can provide it expediently as I have no idea if I can reproduce it without the rest of the project. I can work on getting some branches with a minimal diff that demonstrate the issue as well.

Comment: @PeterCordes they don't; it's 3D and its my own `Vector<float>` impl which is hard coded to 3 dimensions.

Comment: A diff is probably not useful without context; the interesting thing would be to get something on https://godbolt.org/ that compiles to the slow version, but with some changes compiles to the fast version.  Then one can start digging into which aspect of the change matters.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll start on it and let you know if I can get something working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh right, you wrote `Vector` not `std::vector`.  IDK if that gets less confusing / easily mistaken when you've been looking at the codebase longer.  So ok, just a 3-element array.

Comment: I'm stuck at home sick and isolating with cancelled winter break plans so when you've been staring at this as much as I have it's patently obvious but it'd probably be a good call to rename them to `Vector3D` or the like.

Comment: Especially without padding, it can be hard to auto-vectorize geometry stuff for packed 3D or 2D vectors, rather than a struct-of-arrays of `xpos[i]`, `ypos[i]` etc. that would let you check for 4 collisions at a time with 4 consecutive particles.  (If there's an early-out, that might not be as useful.)  Struct-of-Arrays is way more SIMD friendly.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info, especially https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/ which explains the mistake of trying to use SIMD vectors for one geometry vector at once.

Comment: If we're facing an optimiser bug, then there's no logic, only trial and error and collecting data, until the bug is fully understood.

Comment: I already got a similar issues on few physics programs using pointers (~5 years ago). GCC tends to less well optimize codes when pointer/reference to objects are used instead of basic objects. I partially succeed to overcome by setting part of the object to local variables. Sometimes the optimizer wrongly consider that these variables settings are useless and cause the values of the pointer to be dereferenced a lot of time in critical hot loops resulting in a big slowdown... Not to mention this operation break some other optimizations (eg. auto-vectorization & constant propagation & inlining).

Comment: the source does not look exact to me.   and this is not a surprise, it happens, many times performance change with a single tiny change to the code.   for various reasons, even with good optimization (not saying gcc has good optimization).  there is also the issue of compiler version, also no reason to expect any two versions of the same compiler much less any two different compilers to produce the same code.  but subtle changes in a function can affect the construction of the entire function even parts not modified in the high level source

Comment: please provide an example of what you are talking about which includes compiler command line, input source and compiler output, and what completely different, etc?  Depending on how you build, for debug or release, if building differently for the profiler, etc, can also change the compiler output.  a complete function that we can repeat.